# Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

Is it possible that the Visual Studio Ultimate that was installed in my machine didn't include SQL Server Express, they didn't turn any option off when installing, they simply installed it following the default options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It comes with SQL Server, but the instance name is (LocalDb)\v11.0 instead of .\sqlexpress

Comment: Yes it is here. Also you need to remove `User Instance = true` from your connection string if you use it.